# Django, renaming Image files on upload

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 2.2 and Pillow library in the models fields to handle the image files.
I studied a latest online course on Django where tutor used special method during image save to make sure that similarly named images will not override .

But I noticed that when a user upload two different images with same name , Django renames the second file without any function and the files never conflicted when we retrieve.

Is this a new feature in Django ? Should I follow file renaming convention ?

Comment: You do not need to do it, Django does it automatically. I guess it was for the sake of demonstrations only.

Comment: This is builtin django, Even if you uploaded 2 files with the same name x.jpg, they won't override each other and both will be kept